# Tornado receive UDP packets from multicast group

Tags: asynchronous, tornado, multicast

I have a server where I want to receive data from multicast group. Is there any inbuilt function that I can use to receive this multicast UDP packets?

**Edit: Code implementation**
I have implemented the code and that follows like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import struct
import os
import errno
import binascii
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.platform.auto import set_close_exec

class UDPHandler():
    """ 
    Connect to multicast group 
    """
    def __init__(self, ip, port, io_loop):
        self.io_loop    = io_loop
        self._multiIP   = ip
        self.port       = port
        self._sock      = None
        self._socket    = {} # fd -> socket object

    def conn(self):
        """
        Listner to multicast group
        """
        self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self._sock.settimeout(3)
        self._sock.bind(('', self.port))
        self._sock.setblocking(0)
        group   = socket.inet_aton(self._multiIP)
        mreq    = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
        self._sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
        self._socket[self._sock.fileno()] = self._sock
        print("self._sock:", self._sock)

    def onRx(self, data, addr):
        print("addr, data:", addr, len(str(data)))
        print(data)

    def r(self):
        self.conn()
        add_socket_handler(self._sock, self.onRx, self.io_loop)

def add_socket_handler(sock, callback, io_loop):
    def accept_handler(fd, events):
        while True:
            try:
                data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
            except socket.error as e:
                if e.args[0] in (errno.EWOULDBLOCK, errno.EAGAIN):
                    callback(None, None)
            except Exception as e:
                print("except:", e)
                callback(None, None)

            callback(data, address)
    io_loop.add_handler(sock.fileno(), accept_handler, IOLoop.READ)

def periodic():
    # print("periodic")
    None
def main():
    MULTICAST_IP = "224.1.1.10"
    RECEIVE_PORT = 10003
    udpRx = UDPHandler(MULTICAST_IP, RECEIVE_PORT, tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current())
    udpRx.r()
    tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(periodic, 1000).start()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now the problem is is am getting same packet in a loop even if I receive one packet I am receiving the same packet over and over again. Is there something wrong with the code? Especially with `add_socket_handler`?

**Edit 2:** 
I have added a break statement in the while loop that I had in `add_socket_handler` and now it seems to be working good.

```
def add_socket_handler(sock, callback, io_loop):
    def accept_handler(fd, events):
        while True:
            try:
                data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                callback(data, address)
            except socket.error as e:
                if e.args[0] in (errno.EWOULDBLOCK, errno.EAGAIN):
                    raise
            except Exception as e:
                raise
            break ## change in here
    io_loop.add_handler(sock.fileno(), accept_handler, io_loop.READ)
```

Is this how it is suppose to be done ?

Comment: I don't think Tornado has any built-in support for working with UDP sockets. There's an open [issue on Github](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1003) about this. However, if you do a google search on this you will find some articles showing how it can be done. An example: https://gist.github.com/jamiesun/1386e7a63663f0dd4d31

Answer (score 0):

The `break` in your `add_socket_handler` looks backwards. You want to loop until you get EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN. (with the break as written, it will still work, but it will be slightly less efficient and might miss packets).

```
def add_socket_handler(sock, callback, io_loop):
    def read_handler(fd, events):
        while True:
            try:
                data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                callback(data, address):
            except socket.error as e:
                if e.errno in (errno.EWOULDBLOCK, errno.EAGAIN):
                    return
                raise
    io_loop.add_handler(sock, read_handler, io_loop.READ)
```

Other than that, this looks right, although I haven't worked with multicast UDP myself.

Comment: Lets say I want to receive a packet of constant length of 1024. Is it required to ave a loop in that case or will it be good if I just say `sock.recvfrom(1024)` without any loop?

Comment: I believe it will work without a loop, but will be slightly more efficient with one if you are receiving packets rapidly.

Comment: I am receiving packets rapidly and the packets are of constant length. So I thought of using without loop.